# Pass parameter with a command into the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have trouble sending a parameter from my view to my viewmodel.

**View.xaml**:

In my view, I have the following:

```
<TextBox
    MinWidth="70"
    Name="InputId"/>

<Button 
    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=InputId}"
    Content="Add"/>
```

**View.xaml.cs**:

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public MyView(MyViewModel viewModel) : this()
{
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**:

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(ButtonClick);
    }

    private void ButtonClick()
    {
        //Read 'InputId' somehow. 
        //But DelegateCommand does not allow the method to contain parameters.
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to, how I can pass the `InputId` when I click the button to my viewmodel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `<object>` to your delegate command like this :

```
public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; private set; }

     public MyViewModel()
        {
            ButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ButtonClick);
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object yourParameter)
        {
            //Read 'InputId' somehow. 
            //But DelegateCommand does not allow the method to contain parameters.
        }
```

Do you want to get the text of textbox change your xaml to :

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=InputId}"
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.

Comment: After googling for 30 minutes, this was by far the best explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For proper implementation of ICommand/RelayCommand have a look at this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page.

Summary:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }


    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute.Invoke();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

} 


public MyViewModel()
{
    ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ButtonClick);
}

private void ButtonClick(object obj)
{
    //obj is the object you send as parameter.
}
```